# Is it possible to update the structure group which has associated workflow with out Workflow Management right?

Tags: event-system

Is it possible to update the structure group which has associated workflow without Workflow Management rights?

**It's working fine while creating the Structure Group using the below code. But Same StructureGroup once I tried updating is taking very long time and never gets saved.**

```
          EventSystem.Subscribe<StructureGroup, SaveEventArgs>(SetWorkflowToSG, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);

        private void SetWorkflowToSG(StructureGroup sg, SaveEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
         {
            Session newSession = new Session("adminstrator");
            StructureGroup newSg = (StructureGroup)newSession.GetObject(sg.Id);
            if (!(newSg.PageBundleProcess !=null))
            {
                ProcessDefinition pd = (ProcessDefinition)newSession.GetObject("tcmId");
                newSg.PageBundleProcess = pd;                   
                newSg.Save();
            }
            newSession.Dispose();
            }
         }
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the associated workflow to test your hypothesis?

And also to test with/without Workflow Mangement rights?

Comment: On a side note: use a `using()` statement to ensure the Session gets disposed in case of an exception.